# Proving a proposition which leads the irrationality of $\frac{\zeta(5)}{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}$

Tags: integration

**Question** : Is the following $(\star)$ true for $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ ?

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(ax^4+b\pi x^3+c{\pi}^{2}x^2)\log(\sin x)dx=0\Rightarrow  a=b=c=0\qquad(\star)\end{align}$$

**Motivation** : I've been asking [the following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531075/is-frac-zeta-mn-zeta-m-zeta-n-a-rational-number-for-m-n-ge-2-in-m) on MSE :

Is $\frac{\zeta (m+n)}{\zeta (m)\zeta (n)}$ a rational number for $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ where $\zeta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$?

Then, I've just been to able to prove the following theorem :

**Theorem** : If $(\star)$ is true, then $\frac{\zeta (5)}{\zeta (2)\zeta (3)}$ is an irrational number.

However, I can't prove that $(\star)$ is true. Can anyone help?

In the following, I'm going to prove the theorem. Here, note that $(\star)$ is saying that 
$$aI_{4}+bI_{3}+cI_2=0\ (a,b,c\in\mathbb Z)\Rightarrow a=b=c=0$$
where
$$I_m=\frac{1}{{\pi}^{m+1}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^m\log(\sin x)dx.$$

**Lemma** : 
$$I_2=-\frac{1}{24}\log 2+\frac{3}{16}\frac{\zeta (3)}{{\pi}^2}.$$
$$I_3=-\frac{1}{64}\log 2+\frac{9}{64}\frac{\zeta (3)}{{\pi}^2}-\frac{93}{128}\frac{\zeta(5)}{{\pi}^4}.$$
$$I_4=-\frac{1}{160}\log 2+\frac{3}{32}\frac{\zeta (3)}{{\pi}^2}-\frac{45}{64}\frac{\zeta(5)}{{\pi}^4}.$$

**Proof for lemma** : By
$$\log(\sin x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1n\cos(2n\pi)-\log 2$$
for $0\lt x\lt \frac{\pi}{2}$, we get
$${\pi}^{m+1}I_m=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1n\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^m\cos(2n\pi)dx-\frac{1}{m+1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{m+1}\log 2.$$
Here, by utilizing partial integration, we get
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^2\cos(2nx)dx=(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{4n^2},$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^3\cos(2nx)dx=\frac{3}{8n^4}-(-1)^n\frac{3}{8n^4}+(-1)^n\frac{3{\pi}^2}{16n^2},$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^4\cos(2nx)dx=-(-1)^n\frac{3\pi}{4n^4}+(-1)^n\frac{{\pi}^3}{8n^2}.$$
Hence, since we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}=-\left(1-2\cdot\frac{1}{2^3}\right)\zeta(3)=-\frac 34\zeta(3)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^5}=-\left(1-2\cdot\frac{1}{2^5}\right)\zeta(5)=-\frac{15}{16}\zeta(5),$$
we get $I_2,I_3,I_4$ as desired. Now the proof for lemma is completed.

**Proof for theorem** : By the above lemma, we can write
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
        I_2  \\
        I_3 \\
        I_4  \\
        \end{matrix}
\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
        -\frac{1}{24} & \frac{3}{16} & 0 \\
        -\frac{1}{64} & \frac{9}{64} & -\frac{93}{128} \\
        -\frac{1}{160} & \frac{3}{32} & -\frac{45}{64} \\
        \end{matrix}
\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
        \log 2  \\
        {\zeta (3)}/{{\pi}^2} \\
        {\zeta(5)}/{{\pi}^4}  \\
        \end{matrix}
\right)$$
Hence, we get
$$\frac{\zeta(3)}{{\pi}^2}=-\frac 13(1240I_4-1200I_3+264I_2),$$
$$\frac{\zeta(5)}{{\pi}^4}=-\frac 13(120I_4-112I_3+24I_2).$$
Hence, since $\zeta(2)={{\pi}^2}/{6}$, we get
$$\frac{\zeta(5)}{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}=6\frac{{\zeta(5)}/{{\pi}^4}}{{\zeta(3)}/{{\pi}^2}}=6\frac{120I_4-112I_3+24I_2}{1240I_4-1200I_3+264I_2}.$$
Now if $\frac{\zeta(5)}{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}$ is a rational number, then there exist natural numbers $r,s$ such that 
$$\frac{120I_4-112I_3+24I_2}{1240I_4-1200I_3+264I_2}=\frac sr.$$
Hence, we get
$$(120r-1240s)I_4-(112r-1200s)I_3+(24r-264s)I_2=0$$
$$\Rightarrow 120r-1240s=112r-1200s=24r-264s=0$$
$$\Rightarrow 3r=31s,\ 7r=75s,\ r=11s.$$
However, there don't exist such $r,s$. Hence, we know that $\frac{\zeta(5)}{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}$ is an irrational number. Now the proof for theorem is completed.

*Update* : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147238/proving-a-proposition-which-leads-the-irrationality-of-frac-zeta5-zeta2).

Comment: Perhapes I'm wrong, but when you said: $(120r−1240s)I_4−(112r−1200s)I_3+(24r−264s)I_2=0$ $⇒120r−1240s=112r−1200s=24r−264s=0 $ Didn't you assume that $I_4, I_3$ and $I_2$ are L.I?

Comment: Note that $(\star)$ is saying that 
$$aI_{4}+bI_{3}+cI_2=0\ (a,b,c\in\mathbb Z)\Rightarrow a=b=c=0$$

Comment: Maybe my comment is naive. With the help of Wolfram Alpha online calculator I tried integration by parts as starting point the integral in $(\star)$ that is equals to $0$: these  $u=ax^4+b\pi x^3+c{\pi}^{2}x^2$ and $dv=\log(\sin x) dx$. My belief is that one can to deduce **two** equations (that correspond to the real and imaginary part of the resulting integration by parts). I didn't able to finish the integration by parts, this was easy but tedious to collect all terms. I don't know if these two equations, for the **three** unknowns $a,b,c$, are linear independent and  different of the $0=0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $M$ be the $3 \times 3$ matrix of numerical coefficients at the beginning of the proof of main theorem.  I've just verified that its determinant is $3/40960$, hence non-zero.  This shows that $M$ has an inverse (also with a non-null determinant) and then the $3 \times 3$ system can be `inverted' to furnish $\ln{2}$ and the $\zeta{(n)}/\pi^{n-1}$ values in terms of the integrals $I_k$.

F. M. S. Lima, University of Brasilia (fabio-at-fis.unb.br)